# User Restriction for Schema

Tags: oracle

In Oracle 9i & 10g database my application shows these kind of error." The source DB Connection have access to multiple schemas. Restrict the access to required schema for the user.".How can i resolve?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a message coming from your application (or the tool it uses to connect to Oracle), not a message from Oracle itself.